# Laravel join three tables with relationships

Tags: php, laravel, join, eloquent, relationship

How can I join three tables where the foreign ID of each table are part of another,

In the below code, I am trying to get all payments from `PaymentsTable` which have `invoice_id`, and `InvoiceTables` which have `customer_id`,

Here is DB relationships

Table : Customers

```
customer_id; Primary Key
```

Table: Invoices

```
invoice_id: Primary key
customer_id: Foreign Key, Customers
```

Table : Payments

```
payment_id: Primary Key
invoice_id: Foreign Key, Payments
```

```
        $payments = SalesPayments::where('payment_amount', '!=' , NULL)
            ->join('sales_invoices', 'sales_invoices.invoice_id', '=', 'sales_payments.invoice_id')
            ->join('payment_options', 'payment_options.paymentoption_id', '=', 'sales_payments.paymentoption_id')
            //->join('customers', 'customers.customer_id', '=', 'sales_payments.invoice_id')
            ->get();
```

Below Relationship has been tried in Payments model,

```
    public function customers()
    {   

        return $this->hasManyThrough(Customers::class, SalesInvoices::class, 'payment_id' ,'invoice_id', 'payment_id', 'customer_id' );

    }
```

Now with each payment row, I want to get customer information as well, So How can I get it?

Comment: Please show your database relationship schema, as this will help us find the correct query.

Comment: added key constrains

Comment: From your question, I felt like may be you do not need customer information, if that is true, you do not need to join customers table, and if you need it, it more kind of a has-many-through relationship, but need more clarity on your question. when replying to members use @, so that we will get notified.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu, I need to show customer name on Payments view, so I must need customer info. I tried with hasManyThrough but seems failed somewhere, because i have to join 3 tables along with Payments.

Comment: @rjcode Do you only want to select only the records which has relations with all the 3 tables?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu, Yes.

Comment: @rjcode then if you will reverse it also , it should work, customers->whereHas->invoices->with->payments, am I correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231783/discussion-between-rjcode-and-prafulla-kumar-sahu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not defined relationships, we have to go with Query builder, Update your joins as below

```
 $payments = DB::table('sales_payments')
    ->join('sales_invoices', 'sales_invoices.invoice_id', '=', 'sales_payments.invoice_id')
    ->join('customers', 'sales_invoices.customer_id', '=', 'customers.customer_id')
    ->join('payment_options', 'payment_options.paymentoption_id', '=', 'sales_payments.paymentoption_id')
    ->select('sales_payments.*', 'sales_invoices.*', 'customers.*', 'payment_options.*')
    ->get();
```

Then you can add where clause.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume that you need all payment information with its invoices and customer details related to that payment.

If you are Looking for the above Response then You can Simply Retrieve Data with  Nested Eager Loading
Like

```
$payments=SalesPayments::with('salesInvoice.customer')->where(Your condition)->get();
```

In Payments Model

```
 public function SalesInvoice(){
  return $this->BelongsTo(Your sales model class)
}
```

In SalesInvoice Model

```
 public function customer(){
      return $this->BelongsTo(Your user model class)
    }
```